# BitLocker drive got corrupted. Methods to restore data?

Tags: encryption, bitlocker

I'd like to ask for your help regarding a BitLocker drive corruption issue. I am going to write down the steps that caused the problem to help you understand what happened.

1. I saved some data from a 320GB hard drive, and formatted it. It is NOT the Bitlocker drive, and it is unencrypted.
2. I shut down the computer, disconnected the 320GB hard drive, then plugged in the encrypted 1TB drive which was functioning well before that.
3. Started up windows, and noticed the encrypted 1TB drive was being displayed as the formatted and empty 320GB drive.
4. I restarted the machine and plugged the sata cable to another sata port. Windows now sees that the drive is encryped, but says that the disk structure is corrupted and it is unreadable. The lock icon is grey and there is no size or any other data present.

The drive is recognised in the Manage BitLocker Drives menu, and the drive is recognised in the Windows Partition Manager too. If i decrypt the drive, does it makes any sense or just makes matters worse? I did not do anything besides plugging the drive in and trying to open it. The encrypted drive has only one partition.

Is it possible to recover the data? Should i use the 'repair-bde' command? Or use some third-party tools? How bad could the damage be?

Thank you for your time, help is much appreciated!

Comment: Decrypting your drive would overwrite all data on the drive, i would not recommend that solution, since that would make data recovery impossible.

Comment: try cloning your data into another disk using EaseUs partition master software for windows.. That may help

Comment: Thanks to you two, will try that. I also got recommended the M3 Recovery program, which can in theory recover data from bitlocker encrypted drive. If i can, i will experiment with all the methods recommended. Can i set the encrypted disk to read-only? It may be a good idea. Or just don't touch anything on it?